# sorting in wp query based on custom field value

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-field, loop, sort

I am trying to get posts of custom post type 'job_listing' on bases of two custom fields i.e 
1) _job_location
2) _company_name

this is working fine

but I also want to display the posts first that are from the given company i.e if the posts belong to XYZ company then they should be displayed first and then the rest of posts from the given location

```
$related_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'orderby'   =>  $company_name,
    'meta_key'  => '_company_name',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
    'meta_query' => array(    

                        'relation' => 'OR',
                        array(
                              'key'   => '_job_location', 
                              'value' => $job_location,
                              ),
                        array(
                              'key'   => '_company_name', 
                              'value' => $company_name,
                              ),      

                    ),

    );
```

My sorting logic is wrong and I can seem to find out the solution .. so please help me out

Answer (score 0):

"`'orderby'   =>  $company_name,`" should be "`'orderby'   =>  'meta_value',`"

If the value of `_company_name` is numeric - it should be `meta_value_num`.

Note that 'orderby' can only have a predefined value and ordering does it alphabetical

See the possible values at the WP_Query orderby parameter: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

The ordering parameter says: Order alphabetical by the values of `meta_key` - `_company_name` in your case. That is not what your question says.

If you only want posts from a specific company in first place you have to do 2 loops.

One with the `$company_name` as you did and one with excluding `$company_name`

First loops args:

```
$related_args_company = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
    'meta_query' => array(    
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                              'key'   => '_job_location', 
                              'value' => $job_location,
                              ),
                        array(
                              'key'   => '_company_name', 
                              'value' => $company_name,
                              ),      

                    ),

    );
```

Second loops args:

```
$related_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'job_listing',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID ),
    'meta_query' => array(    
                        'relation' => 'AND',
                        array(
                              'key'   => '_job_location', 
                              'value' => $job_location,
                              ),
                        array(
                              'key' => '_company_name',
                              'value' => $company_name,
                              'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
                        ),

                    ),

    );
```

kind regards,
tom

Comment: hi Tom thanks for the inputs.. _company_name  is a string

Comment: i edited now to fit more to your question. note that 'orderby' can only have a predifined value and ordering does it alphabeticaly

Comment: but now you have removed the orderby .. plus why the two loops

Comment: because: the ordering parameter says: order alphabetical by the values of 'meta_key' - thats not what your question says

so if you have a company name "ABC" it will always be displayed before posts with company name "CBA"

if you want a specific company in first place, its the only way.

Comment: hmm I was already doing like that .. with three loops .. one for company , second with AND (company && location )  , then OR (company || location ) ...  all these above withh if else  but I guess you are suggesting to merge the two queries given by you and then display the result

Comment: see at the 'compare' => 'NOT LIKE' key/value pair, that excludes posts with $company_name in the second args

so the first args only get posts with $company_name as value of ´_company_name´ and the second only only posts that dont have ´$company_name´ as value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73451/discussion-between-thomas-fellinger-and-terminator).